# Is it possible to create checkbox tree view in Inno Setup?

Tags: checkbox, inno-setup

I have a plan to create new checkbox. But a checkbox is tree view. So, is it possible to create new checkbox tree view in Inno Setup?

Like checkbox tree view on this picture:

[image: TNewCheckListBox]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`TNewCheckListBox` class](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TNewCheckListBox), just as the "task list" (`WizardForm.TasksList`):

```pascal
var
  CheckListBox: TNewCheckListBox;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  CheckTreePage: TWizardPage;
begin
  CheckTreePage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectTasks, 'My check list box page', '');
  CheckListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(WizardForm);
  CheckListBox.Parent := CheckTreePage.Surface;
  CheckListBox.Top := WizardForm.SelectTasksLabel.Top;
  CheckListBox.Width := WizardForm.TasksList.Width;
  CheckListBox.Left := WizardForm.TasksList.Left;
  CheckListBox.Height :=
    WizardForm.TasksList.Top + WizardForm.TasksList.Height - CheckListBox.Top;
  CheckListBox.WantTabs := True;
  CheckListBox.Color := clBtnFace;
  CheckListBox.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  CheckListBox.MinItemHeight := WizardForm.TasksList.MinItemHeight

  CheckListBox.AddCheckBox(
    'Additional software', '', 0, False, True, False, False, nil);
  CheckListBox.AddCheckBox(
    'Install\Update Microsoft DirectX', '', 1, False, True, False, True, nil);
  CheckListBox.AddCheckBox(
    'Install\Update Microsoft Visual C++', '', 1, False, True, False, True, nil);
  CheckListBox.AddCheckBox(
    'Install\Update NVIDIA PhysX', '', 1, False, True, False, True, nil);
end;
```

[image: TNewCheckListBox]

Comment: how to give actions in this checkbox? if just check it will install all.

Comment: So what do you want really? Did you want to show how to create a *new* tree checklist box? (as you question states) Or did you want to create hierarchical "select task" or "components" page? (what is a completely different question)

Comment: may i change my question? i forget to add words "give it actions when post install".

Comment: Can you first answer my question above?

Comment: Did this answer help you?