# How to create checkboxes at Inno Setup finished page?

Tags: inno-setup

How to create checkboxes at finished page to install DirectX? (dxwebsetup.exe for example).

I see this with some information: [Is it possible to create checkbox tree view in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954188/is-it-possible-to-create-checkbox-tree-view-in-inno-setup) but I want to understand how to give it action to these checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`[Run]` section entry with `postinstall` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=postinstall).

To run an installer you also may need the [`runascurrentuser` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=runascurrentuser) to retain elevated privileges.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\dxwebsetup.exe"; Description: "Install DirectX"; \
  Flags: postinstall runascurrentuser
```

[image: Post install run]