# How to optionally download and install VS redistributable in Inno Setup

Tags: checkbox, inno-setup

How to create checkboxes at task page to download and install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable from URLs?

For example these:

- Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable:
  https://aka.ms/highdpimfc2013x64enu
- Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable:
  https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/5/165255E7-1014-4D0A-B094-B6A430A6BFFC/vcredist_x64.exe

I saw this but I want to download it from URL and install it without adding setup to main program installer: [How to create checkboxes at Inno Setup finished page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836022/inno-setup-how-to-create-checkboxes-at-finished-page)

I also want to delete the setups from these programs (Visual C++ Redistributable) if they are downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start here:
[Install file from Internet in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6887428/850848)

All that you need to modify is to run the code in `NextButtonClick` if a task was selected only (use [`WizardIsTaskSelected` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardistaskselected)).

```pascal
if (CurPageID = wpReady) and WizardIsTaskSelected('InstallVCRedist') then begin
```